# CircularProgressIndicator doesn't animated within ComposeView in Fragment

Tags: android-fragments, android-progressbar

I am having this

in a Fragment

```
 
 return ComposeView(requireContext()).apply {
            config = ChartsConfig()
            setViewCompositionStrategy(ViewCompositionStrategy.DisposeOnViewTreeLifecycleDestroyed)
            setContent { MaterialTheme { 

        val progressValue = 1.0f
        val infiniteTransition = rememberInfiniteTransition()

        val progressAnimationValue by infiniteTransition.animateFloat(
            initialValue = 0.0f,
            targetValue = progressValue,
            animationSpec = infiniteRepeatable(
                animation = tween(durationMillis = 4000, easing = LinearEasing)
            )
        )
        println(progressAnimationValue)
        CircularProgressIndicator(progress = progressAnimationValue)

 } }
        }
```

If I try the same composable within a compose test project activity it animates just fine.
However, it doesnt' when I put it in a fragment as shown here

Comment: Are you sure that your phone has animation activated ?